# Currently very confused on the "working of classes" in c++, could anybody provide a intuitive explanation with examples?

Tags: c++, function, class, dev-c++

I'm new to programming and just started to learn the bare minimum in terms of c++, could anybody give a heads up and provide a intuitive and easy to understand explanation on "working classes" in c++ and the methods to use them in a program and incorporating "function" in the classes.
any links to useful study material are also helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic at StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm helpless in this regard, as far as coding is concerned i'm a complete noob, if StackOverflow is not the best place for this then  a simple suggestion or link to any relevant site or source is also appreciated.

Comment: @amn_ron There are plenty of tutorials, books and examples available in the internet. Just lookup _object oriented programming_ and/or _classes_ with google or any other search engine of your choice.

Comment: You can learn basics of OOP here - https://dev.to/charanrajgolla/beginners-guide---object-oriented-programming. They are same in every OOP language. For C++, use your uni textbook.

Comment: Off-topic here. Read some good introduction to [Programming in C++](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) and read about [virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning. I  think it's helpful to treat a class instance as a bunch of shared parameters among a group of related functions:
So, instead of:

```
fun1(a, b, c);
fun2(a, b, c, d);
fun3(a, b, c, e);
```

do this:

```
class MyClass {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    MyClass(int a, int b, int c);
    int fun1();
    int fun2(int d);
    int fun3(int e);
}

 MyClass mc(a, b, c);
 mc.fun1();
 mc.fun2(d);
 mc.fun3(e);
```

This way you have less parameters to pass and less duplicate code(ie. repeatedly passing `a`, `b`, `c` to several different functions, and make sure they are in the right order), which means less error prone code.

Answer (score 1):

In object-oriented programming languages, a class is a logic unit that does something, class can also have names of your application's domain.

For example, in a mathematical library, you can find a class like `Vector` or `Matrix` and you can have operations like `dot` `cross` and so on. Here a simple, not working snippet:

```
class Vector3d {
public:   // public interface
  // constructor of the class: what happen when I create the class?    
  Vector3d() : _x{0.0}, _y{0.0}, _z{0.0} {}

  // get components
  double x() const { return _x; }
  double y() const { return _y; }
  double z() const { return _z; }

  // set components
  double x(doulbe newX) { _x = newX; }
  double y(doulbe newY) { _y = newY; }
  double z(doulbe newZ) { _z = newZ; }

  // add an operation
  Vector3d& operator+= (const Vector3d& vec)
  {
    x(vec.x());
    y(vec.y());
    z(vec.z());

    return *this;
  }

private: // hidden stuff
  double _x, _y, _z;
};
```

As you can see classes expose a public interface, and hide the implementation. The main advantage of writing classes is that you can have use word of your domain problem and have expressions like:

```
Vector3d a{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, b{0.0, 1.0, 0.0};
auto c = a + b;
auto d = cross(a, b);
```

Unfortunately, it's not easy to design good classes and it requires a lot of practice and experience... there are a lot of guidelines to keep in mind, this is true of all programming languages.

I usually prefer free functions to methods when is possible so to my `Vector3d` class I will have free functions like `operator+` `dot` and `cross`

```
Vector3d opertor+ (const Vector3d& v1, const Vector3d& v2)
{
   return {v1.x() + v2.x(), v1.y() + v2.y(); v1.z() + v2.z();
}
```